# Python Regex A not B

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a Regex expression to find set of characters with exemption.

```py
n = 'abcd0123456789'
re.findall(r'[0-9^4^6]', n)
```

gives output

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

I was expecting output excluding `'4'` and `'6'`

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '8', '9']
```

I can do like

```py
re.findall(r'[0-3|5|7-9]', n)
```

Bur is there better way to express `0-9 except 4 and 6`?

Comment: Why do you expect that? `[0-9^4^6]` simply means numbers or `^`, where 4 and 6 are redundantly repeated. The expression you probably seek is `[0-357-9]`

Comment: And just to spell it out, `[0-3|5|7-9]` also matches a literal `|`. The syntax inside `[...]` is simply a list of characters, with a simple range notation and a simple negation mechanism whereby the list is characters _not_ to match if the first character is a caret.

Comment: A character set is either positive or negative - there's no way to mix both types into one set.  `[0-9](?<![46])` would be one solution - the negative lookbehind will disallow 4 or 6 in the positive set.

Comment: Related: [Match Everything from Set, except one character](/q/3850886/4518341)

Comment: @tripleee Yes. This is correct `[|]` will match literal `|`. Thank you for point out.

Comment: @jasonharper the expression `[0-9](?<![46])` is what I was looking for. Thnak you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0-9^4^6]` is indeed incorrect.

`[0-9^4^6]` matches `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `^`, `4`, `^`, `6`, so
`[0-9^4^6]` matches `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `^`

`[0-3|5|7-9]` is also incorrect.

`[0-3|5|7-9]` matches `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `|`, `5`, `|`, `7`, `8`, `9`, so
`[0-3|5|7-9]` matches `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `|`.

`[0-357-9]` is correct.

---

You're asking for a set difference.

The third-party `regex` module supports this.

```
[[0-9]--[46]]        # Requires the `VERSION1` flag
```

Demo:

```py
import regex
bool( regex.match("[[0-9]--[46]]", "2", regex.VERSION1) )   # True
bool( regex.match("[[0-9]--[46]]", "4", regex.VERSION1) )   # False
bool( regex.match("(?V1:[[0-9]--[46]])", "2") )             # True
bool( regex.match("(?V1:[[0-9]--[46]])", "4") )             # False
```

The builtin module `re` does not support set differences. However, we can use a lookbehind to approximate it.

```
[0-9](?<![46])
```

Demo:

```py
import re
bool( re.match("[0-9](?<![46])", "2") )   # True
bool( re.match("[0-9](?<![46])", "4") )   # False
```

Comment: Yes. I just tested this as tripleee commented. I am still learning. Thank you. `[0-9](?!<=[46])` works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^` in a character class to negated it, but it should be at the start in that case.

With a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), you might also say that you want any digit except for `4` and `6`

```
[^\D46]
```

See the [regex matches here](https://regex101.com/r/8cD1wH/1)

As using the negated character class could also match digits in other languages, you can pass the `re.ASCII` flag:

```
import re

pattern = r"[^\D46]"
n = 'abcd0123456789'

print(re.findall(pattern, n, re.ASCII))
```

Output

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: I call this technique double-negation because one changes `\x` into `[^\X...]`. Unfortunately, it only works if you want to exclude characters from a negatable non-bracketed character class (such as `\d`). Since that's not the case for the OP, the technique can't be used to help them, and your pattern must be incorrect. Specifically, your pattern matches 368 different characters (or thereabouts), but it should only match 8. For example, [it matches](https://regex101.com/r/8cD1wH/2) the string produced by `chr(0x660)`.

Comment: That said, the technique can be used with a slight tweak. Since `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` when the `re.ASCII` flag is provided, so `[^\D46]` works when the `re.ASCII` flag is provided.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, you are absolutely right.